# How do I grow a new African Violet from a leaf?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, propagation, african-violets

Two days ago I was admiring a friend's indoor [African Violet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saintpaulia), and she told me I could grow my own from a leaf. I've never heard of being able to do that with any plant. She gave me three leaves, each with a stem about two inches long, and told me if I put them in some potting soil, water them from the bottom, and leave the pot at room temperature in indirect sunlight, I'll see new plants in a few weeks. I did that. An online search confirmed that violets can be propagated this way, but the sites differed as to the process. Should I leave them as they are or do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are good instructions. Another propagation method that is also quite successful is to get a glass of water and cover it with wax paper. Use a knife to cut a slit in the wax paper and insert the stem of the leaf in the water.

It takes longer to grow roots and but you have a more well established plant.  A small new plant will start from the base of the stem or you can plant it out when there are some roots.

One thing that will help success is to keep the environment warm, as in over 20 Deg c or around 68 deg F.  Bright diffuse sunlight is also an aid.

Comment: We keep the house at around 66 deg F during the day, and 62 at night (11pm-10am). Should I put these violets under, or near to, grow lights?

Comment: @Sue Grow lights are good, even better is a heated propagation mat that provides gentle bottom heat.

Comment: All I can advise is patience.  All the leaves are growing roots by using the energy stored in the leaf.  Sometimes it takes a while and sometimes it does not work at all.